# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python-2.7

For these lines of code in python 2.7:

```
print performer[0]
print performer[0].split(">")[1]
```

I get

```
<span itemprop="name performers">Lindsey Stirling Tickets</span>
```

Ok result here, but

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\format.py", line 51, in <module>
  print performer[0].split(">")[1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Text originates from beautiful soup so not sure it type is messing it up. Have used split before but never had these issues.

Comment: Post more code. It looks like `performer[0].split` is `None`, so `performer[0]` probably isn't a normal `str`ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, didn't realize that list(performer) only affected list not the individual items.

Iterating through to change each one fixed it. Items were still:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```